# PHP Static Calls from a Object

Tags: php, class, object, static, call

I have a PHP class method which is using a static function from with a another class. How do i enable that static function to modify variables within the calling class.. Example as follows:

PARENT:

```
class sys_core
{
   public $test = 'no';

   // --------------------
   public function __construct()
   {
   }

   // --------------------
   public function init()
   {
      sys_loader::load_config('123');
      print $this->test;
   }

   // --------------------
   // --------------------
   // --------------------
   // --------------------
   // --------------------

} // END Class
```

STATIC CLASS

```
class sys_loader
{
   private $registry = array();

   // --------------------
   public static function load_config($file)
   {
      $this->test = 'yes';
   }

   // --------------------
   // --------------------
   // --------------------
   // --------------------

} // END Class
```

ERROR:

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context
```

Comment: You can not access object variables from static context. Just do a standard call, not a static call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see it, sys_loader can modify sys_core's $test 3 ways:

1) sys_loader is passed a reference to sys_core->test,
2) sys_loader returns a new value for it or
3) equip sys_core with a setter for $test and pass sys_loader a reference to sys_core.
   With that reference, sys_loader can access whatever variables and functions sys_core allows.

Here are the bits I changed/added to make #3 work:

Example use:

```
$sc = new sys_core();
$sc->setConfigFile('123');
$sc->init();
```

Output:
123yes

class sys_core

```
// new
private $configFile = null;

// new
function getConfigFile() {
  return $this->configFile;
}

// new
function setConfigFile($value) {
  $this->configFile = $value;
}

// new
function setTest($value) {
  $this->test = $value;
}


public function init()
{
// sys_loader::load_config('123');
  sys_loader::load_config($this);
  print $this->test;
}
```

class sys_loader

```
// public static function load_config($file)
public static function load_config($caller)
{
// $this->test = 'yes';
  $caller->setTest('yes');
// new, example
  $config = $caller->getConfigFile();
// new, example
  echo $config;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, you can pass a reference to your sys_core instance as a parameter to the sys_loader::load_config method:

```
class sys_core
{...
    public function init()
    {
       sys_loader::load_config('123', $this);
       print $this->test;
    }    
 ...
}

class sys_loader
{
  ...
   // --------------------
   public static function load_config($file, $core)
   {
      $core->test = 'yes';
   }
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. By definition, `static` means not tied to any object. (What are you trying to accomplish here?)

Static methods are per class, they can take in parameters and modify [static](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php) variables. Figure out what you need, draw a diagram, and implement it.

Comment: I want to have a class act as a container which contains all my loading functions.. So my CORE class will use functions from within my loader class to require in configs (in this instance), placing the contents into a registry within the core.

Comment: Just to add another note.. There is no need to create objects out of the static classes as i just require functions from them. I am using classes for organisation only really.

Comment: Updated answer, see if it helps. If you really understand the static/non-static concept, then solving your problem should be straightforward.

Comment: @Lee: If you only need functions, you should only use functions. I have the feeling you're making your life needlessly complicated. Set the variables into a global object or array, and just tell a loader function to where load that into. That works as well with static variables and static class functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can access any public member outside of that class, private members can only be accessed by the class itself, and protected members can be accessed by sub-classes.

`self` is used for static members...one per class.

`this` is used for non-static members...one per instance.